# How to filter the duplicate objects inside an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I am using underscore.js plugin for this my code 
I tried here **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5TD9/2/)**

```
var basket=[{
            "basketitems":[{"items":[]}],
            "itemdetails":[{
                "amountPledged": "100",
                "bActivity": "Handloom Work",
                "bCity": "Nadia"
                },
                {
                "amountPledged": "100",
                "bActivity": "Saree Business",
                "bCity": "Nadia"
                },
                {
                "amountPledged": "100",
                "bActivity": "Saree Business",
                "bCity": "Nadia"
                }],
            "cartdetails":[],
            "paymentdetails":[],
            "userdetails":[]    
            }];

var tempbasket=_.uniq(basket);
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tempbasket);
```

Help me to fix this

Comment: Is there way to filter by key[CityName] inside the itemdetails object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example,

```
basket[0].itemdetails = _.uniq(basket[0].itemdetails, JSON.stringify)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g5TD9/3/

To filter by a specific field, pass a function that takes an object and returns that field:

```
_.uniq(itemdetails, function(x) { return x.bCity })
```

Docs: [`uniq`](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq)

Comment: Is there way to filter by key[bCity] inside the itemdetails object?

Comment: @SureshPattu: sure, just pass a function that returns it as a second argument: `_.uniq(list,function(item){return item.whatYouWant})`

Answer (score 1):

Two things are there:

**1.** First of all, you should do:

```
basket[0].itemdetails=_.uniq(basket[0].itemdetails);
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(basket);
```

**Not:**

```
var tempbasket=_.uniq(basket);
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tempbasket);
```

**2.** Second thing is, as your `basket[0].itemdetails` is array of objects, so that `_.unique` will not work there. Becayse two different objects in javascript can not be equal.

**Example:**

```
var x = {a:5};
var y = {a:5};

console.log(x == y); // false;
```

So, this trick will not work here. You will have to do this manually. Good luck!

**===== Edit =====**

Here is working solution:

```
basket[0].itemdetails = _.unique(basket[0].itemdetails, function(item,key,a){
    return item.bActivity;
});

console.log(basket[0].itemdetails);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F4Q4u/3/

*Enjoy JScripting!!*

Comment: Is there way to filter by key[bCity] inside the itemdetails object?

Answer (score 0):

```
var tempbasket=_.uniq(basket[0].itemdetails.map(function(d){return JSON.stringify(d)}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of the existing JSON and iterate over it to check the duplicates.

```
var basketCopy = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( basket ) );
basketCopy[0].itemdetails = [];
_.each(basket[0].itemdetails, function(item) {
    if(!_.findWhere(basketCopy[0].itemdetails, item)) {
        basketCopy[0].itemdetails.push(item);
    }
});
console.log(basketCopy); // Your unique itemdetails list
```

Answer (score -1):

I've never used underscore myself, but taking a (not so) wild guess, it checks if the first indexOf the item is the same as its actual index. Because JS treats logically identical objects as different objects, it will also treat them as different. You might have to write your own unique() function to properly deal with objects.